# Webdriverio v7 remote selenium grid

Tags: selenium-grid, webdriver-io

How can be webdriver-io v7 Tests run with an intranet Selenium Grid? According to Company policies is the intranet Selenium Grid only option? I can find in Webdriverio services for stand-alone-selenium, chrome driver, and some cloud services but not for an internal Company Selenium Grid Instances

Comment: are you asking how to run your tests on an internal selenium grid?

Comment: Yes, if you mean  internal selenium Grid, which is accessible within Company but not from public internet

Comment: Yes. that is what I mean.

Comment: Is there any specific problem are you facing ?

Answer (score 3):

change this in config file.
when run in Grid

```
services: [],
hostname: your.domain.without.http.and.without.port,
port: 4444,
path: '/wd/hub/',
protocol: 'http',
```

when run in local

```
services:  ['chromedriver'],
```

in local run, hostname, port, path and protocol are can be any value or removed, since framework does not pick up this value.
Dependency "wdio-chromedriver-service" needs to be installed since it is essential for local run.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue. Below steps did the trick for me!

```
>  hostname: 'selenium.company.internal',
>     port: <number>,
>     path: '/wd/hub/',
>     protocol: 'https',
```

Add the above values in wdio.conf.js file.

- Remove `wdio-chromedriver-service` dependency from your package.json
  file.
- Do a `npm i` or `npm ci`
- Run your tests (`npm run test` in my
  case)

BOOM! Your test execution will be started in the grid

Answer (score 0):

There is no need an extra webdriverio service like Selenium Standalone Service or ChromDriver service. What is needed the right wdio.conf.js or wdio.conf.ts . Important Fields are hostname, port, path, protocol and capabilities.

```
export const config: WebdriverIO.Config = {
    //
    // ====================
    // Runner Configuration
    // ====================
    //
    // WebdriverIO allows it to run your tests in arbitrary locations (e.g. locally or
    // on a remote machine).
    runner: 'local',
    //
    // =====================
    // Server Configurations
    // =====================
    // Host address of the running Selenium server. This information is usually obsolete as
    // WebdriverIO automatically connects to localhost. Also, if you are using one of the
    // supported cloud services like Sauce Labs, Browserstack, Testing Bot or LambdaTest you don't
    // need to define host and port information because WebdriverIO can figure that out
    // according to your user and key information. However, if you are using a private Selenium
    // backend you should define the host address, port, and path here.
    //
    hostname: 'selenium.company.internal',
    port: <number>,
    path: '/wd/hub/',
    protocol: 'https',
```

........

capabilities: [{

```
    // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
    // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
    // 5 instances get started at a time.
    'maxInstances': 5,
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'acceptInsecureCerts': true,
    // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
    // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
    // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
    // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        'args': [
            // Runs Chrome in headless mode.
            "--headless",
            // Temporarily needed if running on Windows.
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--window-size=2000,1024",
            // dont show the 'this browser is controlled by software' bar
            "--disable-infobars"
        ]
    }
}],
```